# How can a PC determine what planes a Cubic Gate is linked to?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, planes

The description of the [Cubic Gate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/cubic-gate) (DMG, p. 160) states:

> The six sides of the cube are each keyed to a different plane of existence, one of which is the Material Plane. The other sides are linked to planes determined by the DM.

I'm the DM in this situation, and I've decided which planes the cube is linked to. However, since the item does not require attunement, **is there any way for the PC who now has the cube to determine those planes other than by experimentation?**

(If the item did require attunement, I'd assume that attuning to it would let you know, since attuning to items allows you to understand its properties, but that's not the case here as it doesn't require attunement.)

Comment: As per the artwork for Cubic Gate, why not with symbols on the item itself?

Comment: @Yvihs Y'know, I almost added that to my question, but if there are no rules suggesting it, I was worried that might come under "as a DM, you can invent whatever ways you like", and didn't want this to become a polling question for "how would you do it"? Otherwise yes, I may very well go with that if the answers confirm my suspicion that "RAW, it's just via experimentation".

Comment: Your note about attunement is actually a misunderstanding: attunement doesn't reveal an item's properties. The relevant rules text [(this can't be the same short rest used to learn the item's properties)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement) is what led to my answer, but I didn't have the reputation to comment before I made it

Comment: Not an answer, but, ultimately the question boils down to this:  How easy do you WANT it to be for them?  Easy:  Tell them.  Hard:  Make them really really work for it.

Comment: @Chris That's a very good point, I was mistaken on that. Thanks for your answer, that's also helped to clear that up.

Comment: @ReginaldBlue That's basically the question _behind_ this question; I want to know what the players _can_ do RAW, _then_ I can decide how easy I want it to be for them. By the looks of things, they can just short rest, so unless I house rule that away (or they don't think of it), I can't do much to _stop_ them from learning all the properties by themselves anyway...

Comment: @NathanS Of course you can. You decide how much to tell them.

Comment: @MarkWells You mean, if they learn the properties via a short rest, I can just tell them about that it casts _gate_ and _plane shift_, and that each side takes them "somewhere", but I don't necessarily have to tell them where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of identifying a magical item, and the DMG [lists a few options](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#IdentifyingaMagicItem) besides experimentation:

## Identify

> The [*identify*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify) spell is the fastest way to reveal an item's properties.

## Short Rest

> Alternatively, a character can focus on one magic item during a short rest, while being in physical contact with the item. At the end of the rest, the character learns the item's properties, as well as how to use them. Potions are an exception; a little taste is enough to tell the taster what the potion does.

## The item says a lot about itself

> Sometimes a magic item carries a clue to its properties. The command word to activate a ring might be etched in tiny letters inside it, or a feathered design might suggest that it's a ring of feather falling.

Source: I copied most of this from [this related answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/123997/41357). I found it quite interesting that, even without attunement, a short rest can be used to identify. Actually, RAW, the attunement short rest (if any) [comes after the identify short rest!](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement)

> (this can't be the same short rest used to learn the item's properties)

Comment: Given that the premise of my question was flawed (i.e. that I thought the short rest to attune _was the same_ short rest to learn its properties), and this answer clears that up, I'm going to accept this answer. But PJRZ's answer was still helpful with the detail about the symbols on the Cubic Gate's art matching the symbols in the PHB's planes section, so honourable mentions to that answer too.

Answer (score 13):

The description doesn't say so likely it would be up to the DM.

It's interesting to note, however, that the illustration of the cube shows each side with a different symbol. And those symbols match up to the symbols accompanying the description of the planes in the Player's Handbook! (As somebody pointed out in the DnDBeyond comments).

If you decide to use this method, you could decide that a character could use an Arcana check to determine the symbol and thus the plane. Or, if nobody is proficient in Arcana (or you want them to work for their knowledge), you could require the players to investigate around the city for a knowledgeable sage or for access to a library for a bit of old-fashioned research.

The [Identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify) spell is another alternative. It allows the caster to know the properties of an item and that could, if you allow it, determine the meaning of each face.

Comment: I completely forgot about the _identify_ spell! Probably because the party doesn't have a wizard. That's interesting to note about the symbols, though; they do match with the PHB, so "good old fashioned research" may well be what I go with...

Comment: Half of Divination school could help: Commune, Contact other Plane, Divination, Legend Lore...